# My jQuery selector returns a HTML tag and its contents, but I can't get at the contents alone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to access all visible values on my page wrapped in `span` tags. I use the selector `$(rows[i]).find("span:visible")[0]` (the `[i]` because I'm iterating through an array) and am returned a set like this:

```
<span class=​"size">​7​</span>​
<span class=​"size">​29​</span>​
<span class=​"size">​14​</span>​
```

What I'd like is to get at those numbers themselves, free from the tags. But if I change my selector to

`$(rows[i]).find("span:visible")[0].innerHTML`

`$(rows[i]).find("span:visible")[0].text`

`$(rows[i]).find("span:visible")[0].textContent`

`$(rows[i]).find("span:visible")[0].html`

or any other selector I think should work, I get back 'undefined' or 'cannot retrieve property X of undefined' errors.

What should I be using here?

Comment: try $($(rows[i]).find("span:visible")[0]).text() instead?

Comment: Have you tried `$(rows[i]).find("span:visible").html()`

Answer (score 0):

The selector gets you a jQuery set of the matching spans. Using `[0]` and such on it gives you the raw DOM element. If you want the text of each individual span, use `.eq(x).text()` instead:

```
var spans = $(rows[i]).find("span:visible");
console.log("Text of first matching span: " + spans.eq(0).text());
console.log("Text of second matching span: " + spans.eq(1).text());
// ...
```

Or in a loop:

```
$(rows[i]).find("span:visible").each(function(index) {
    console.log("Text of span " + index + ": " + $(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$(rows[i]).find("span:visible")[0].html();
```

OR

```
$(rows[i]).find("span:visible")[0].text();
```

or

```
$(rows[i]).find("span:visible")[0].get().innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

That *should* work... and this [does work](http://jsfiddle.net/8sww5/):

```
console.log($(".1").find("span:visible")[0]); //logs the first span
console.log($(".1").find("span:visible")[0].text); //logs the text content of the first span

//in a loop - logs the content of each span in jm
$(".1").find("span:visible").each( function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

My expectation is that there there is a typo somewhere in your code that'll you'll have to find and fix.